# Xamarin forms, Broadcast Receiver dosen't hit when application is closed

Tags: xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver, xamarin.forms, connectivity

I'm developing an app using Xamarin forms, I have a Broadcast receiver which monitors connectivity change. It works perfectly when application is active, but when I close my application(just slide it out from the recent apps tray) the Broadcast receiver stops working.I'm not able find where i'm committing mistake.
Below is my manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.ETMS.taskmanagement.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:name="com.ETMS.taskmanagement.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

below is my Broadcast Receiver :

```
namespace ETMS.Droid.Receiver
 {
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true,Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" })]
    class ConnectivityReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.Debug("ETMS CONNECTIVITY ", "Reached Connectivity");
            LocalPreferenceManager mManager = new LocalPreferenceManager(context);
            bool hasNetwork = !intent.GetBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.ExtraNoConnectivity, false);
            if (hasNetwork)
            {
                bool authenticate = GeofenceSPService.AuthenticateSp();

                if (authenticate)
                {
                    GeofenceSPService.SyncGeofenceToServer(mManager);
                    GeofenceSPService.LogTrace("Raj", "Connectivity Receiver : " + authenticate);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Error("ETMS CONNECTIVITY ", "Reached Connectivity");
            }
        }
        public bool IsConnected(Context context)
        {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo;
            bool isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.IsConnectedOrConnecting;
            return isConnected;
        }
        private void SendNotification(string networkDetails, Context context)
        {
            // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            // Construct a task stack
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(context);
            // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
            stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
            // push the content Intent onto the stack.
            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(notificationIntent);
            // Get a PendingINtent containing the entire backstack
            PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
            //Define the notification settings.
            builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.networkoff)
               .SetContentTitle(networkDetails)
               .SetContentText("Network Connectivity")
               .SetContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);
            // Dismiss the notification once the user touches it.
            builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
            // Get an instance of the Notification manager
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            mNotificationManager.Notify(0, builder.Build());

        }
    }
}
```